# Is this simply assuming an Ito semimartingale.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am reading a paper where they start by assuming some process follows
$$
\frac{dX_t}  {X_{t-}} = \alpha_t dt + \sqrt{V_t} dW_t + \int_{x > -1} x \tilde{\mu}(dt, dx) 
$$
with $\alpha_t$ and $V_t$ cadlag, $W$ a Brownian motion, $\mu$ an integer valued random measure with compensator $\nu(dt,dx) = a_t dt \otimes \nu(dx)$ for some process and Levy measure $\nu$ and the associated martingale measure is $\tilde{\mu} = \mu - \nu$.

To try and understand this I have (tried to) read the relevant parts in Limit theorems by Jacod and Shiryaev and Discretization of processes by Protter and Jacod, so I can see the similarities to what they call Îto semimartingales, but I just can make any sense to the lower limit.  Is this just assuming the process follows an Îto semimartingale or is it something more?

Edit:
Its a version of this paper:
https://economics.indiana.edu/home/about-us/events/conferences-and-workshops/2013/files/2013-11-05-01.pdf
see page 4.

Comment: What do you mean by "lower limit"? $x>-1$...?

Comment: Exactly! I was hoping you would pick up the question :)

Comment: Well, I can't help you much about that. More frequently, you'll see integrals of the following form $$\int_{|x|<1} x \, \tilde{\mu}(dt,dx) + \int_{|x| \geq 1} x \, \mu(dt,dx).$$ The splitting of the integral is due to the fact that we have to ensure the existence of the integrals. However, for this particular SDE, I can't tell you why this lower bound was chosen.

Comment: @saz Yea. That is the same as I have seen, so it looks kind of similar, but on the other hand also strange.